# Ruby on Rails Why can I not log in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

In my Ruby on Rails application, I have made it so that users can register but once the server is stopped and I load the page again they are not logged in (which is fine) but when I click "Log In" I get the following error:

```
NameError in Sessions#new
Showing C:/Sites/Thor/UnderConstruction/ThorCinema/app/views/sessions/new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined local variable or method `sessions_create_path' for #<#<Class:0x6829bd8>:0x57ce460>
```

The `sessions_create_path` is in views/session/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="form1"> 
<%= form_tag sessions_create_path, :method => :get do %>
<fieldset>          
        <legend>Please Log In</legend>                  
        <div>                   
            <%= label_tag :name,'Name:' %>
            <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] , :autofocus => true %> 
        </div>                  
        <div>                   
            <%= label_tag :password, 'Password:' %>             
            <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
        </div>
        <div>                   
            </br>                   
            <%= submit_tag "Login" %>               
        </div>      
    </fieldset> 
<% end %> <!-- form_tag --> 
</br>   
<%= link_to 'Back', :back %>
```

and the sessions_controller create method is:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by name: params[:name]
    if user and user.authenticate params[:password]
        # 'logging in' is performed by saving a user's id in the session variable
        session[:user_id] = user.id

        # redirect to last page or root_path (products/index.html.erb')
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash.now.alert = "Invalid user/password"
        render :new
    end
end
```

The login button is in application.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Log In", login_path %>
```

Routes.rb:

```
controller :sessions do
    get  'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    get 'logout' => :destroy
end

resources :users


get 'films/index'
get 'categories/index'
get 'certificates/index'

resources :films
resources :categories
resources :certificates
resources :showings
root 'films#index'

post 'films/search', to: 'films#search'

post 'films/display_products_by_genre', :to => 'films#display_products_by_genre'
get 'films/display_products_by_genre', :to => 'films#display_products_by_genre'

post 'films/multi_find', :to => 'films#multi_find'
get 'films/multi_find', :to => 'films#multi_find'

match '*a', to: 'errors#routing', via: [:get, :post]
```

Can anyone tell me why the log in isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to log out using this:   `<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>`

and then click the log In button.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the problem is that there isn't a user logged in to log out, and when adding in that code I get the error: `undefined local variable or method destroy_user_session_path`

Comment: Have you kept   devise_for :users  in your routes?

Comment: No my routes does not have that, whereabouts should it go?

Comment: Oh, that created the problem. So, please add it in your routes.rb file which is inside config directory. Now, I hope your problem will be solved. :-)

Comment: Adding it in gives me this error: `undefined method 'devise_for' `

Comment: comment this lines if you use devise_for :users  controller :sessions do
    get  'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    get 'logout' => :destroy
end

Comment: I have done and the login now works, but clicking the logout button does nothing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70965/discussion-between-sansarp-and-benjs-1).

Comment: Fixed it, I didn't have the destroy method in the sessions_controller set up, thank you for all your help!